# wpf change listview selection color and remove white

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, colors, selection

I tried multiple times to remove that kind of white glossy effect in wpf,
But even when changing everything to #1F419A I still have that white thing.
[Top of the selection white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cu6y6.png)
Is there a way to fix this?
kind regards
LD

```
<ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
          <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background"  Value="#1F419A"/>
                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#1F419A"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1F419A"/>
                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#1F419A"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
 </ListView.Resources>
```

This is what I tried, I expected all to be in that color

Comment: That style, you don't want to have, must be due to the default control template. Try to modify control template for `ListViewItem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The highlight effects and other layout details like background elements are always implemented in the `ControlTemplate`. In order to change it you would have to override the default `ControlTemplate` and add your triggers to the `ControlTemplate.Triggers` collection. You can find an example of the default templates at [Microsoft Docs: Control Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/control-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

```xml
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ListViewItem}"
       TargetType="ListViewItem">
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
          Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
          Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Border x:Name="Border"
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
          <GridViewRowPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
        </Border>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                    Property="Background"  
                    Value="#1F419A" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border"  
                    Property="BorderBrush" 
                    Value="#1F419A" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Border"  
                    Property="Background" 
                    Value="#1F419A" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                    Property="BorderBrush" 
                    Value="#1F419A" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: This was the answer to my question! thankyou!